# Переписать TCP клиент-сервер с IPv4 на IPv6

Tags: linux, tcp, ipv6

Я пытаюсь переписать свою программу, чтобы клиент с сервером взаимодействовали по IPv6 . Все скомпилировалось вроде бы корректно.Сервер запустился, но при попытке подключить клиента к серверу выдает connect: Network is unreachable
Подскажите, пожалуйста. в чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

сервер:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFLEN 512
#define MAXLINE 255
char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];


char point [9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

char *my_itoa(int num, char *str)
{
        if(str == NULL)
        {
                return NULL;
        }
        sprintf(str, "%d", num);
        return str;
}


//#ifdef MUTEX
pthread_mutex_t lock;
//#endif

void *tcp_work(void *);



int check () 
{
    if (((*point=='X')&&(*(point+1)=='X')&&(*(point+2)=='X'))||((*(point+3)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+5)=='X'))||((*(point+6)=='X')&&(*(point+7)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*point=='X')&&(*(point+3)=='X')&&(*(point+6)=='X'))||((*(point+1)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+7)=='X'))||((*(point+2)=='X')&&(*(point+5)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*point=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*(point+2)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+6)=='X')))
    { return 1;}
    else if (((*point=='O')&&(*(point+1)=='O')&&(*(point+2)=='O'))||((*(point+3)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+5)=='O'))||((*(point+6)=='O')&&(*(point+7)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*point=='O')&&(*(point+3)=='O')&&(*(point+6)=='O'))||((*(point+1)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+7)=='O'))||((*(point+2)=='O')&&(*(point+5)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*point=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*(point+2)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+6)=='O')))
    { return 2;}
    if (((*point=='X')||(*point=='O'))&&((*(point+1)=='X')||(*(point+1)=='O'))&&((*(point+2)=='X')||(*(point+2)=='O'))&&((*(point+3)=='X')||(*(point+3)=='O'))&&((*(point+4)=='X')||(*(point+4)=='O'))&&((*(point+5)=='X')||(*(point+5)=='O'))&&((*(point+6)=='X')||(*(point+6)=='O'))&&((*(point+7)=='X')||(*(point+7)=='O'))&&((*(point+8)=='X')||(*(point+8)=='O')))
    { return 3;}
    return 0;
}
int g_port;

struct s_Data{
    char filename[50];
    char data[MAXLINE];
    int number;
    int flag;
}sendData, recvData;



void reaper(int sig)
{
  int status;
  while(wait3(&status, WNOHANG, (struct rusage *)0) >= 0);
}

int MAX (int x, int y)
{
 if (x>y)
 return x;
 else
 return y;
}


int create_tcp()
{
  int sockfd;
  struct sockaddr_in6 servaddr,clientaddr;  
  if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
      perror("Error open Socket.");
      exit(1);
    }
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  bzero(&clientaddr, sizeof(clientaddr));
  servaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  servaddr.sin6_addr =  in6addr_any;
   //  inet_pton(AF_INET6, in6addr_any, &servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
  servaddr.sin6_port = htons(g_port);
socklen_t len;
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)& servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0)
     {
      perror("bind server error");
      exit(2);
     }  
   else{
      printf("Server TCP : bind() successful\n");

    len = sizeof(servaddr); 
    if (getsockname(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, &len)==-1)
        perror("getsockname");
    else
        printf("Port number %d\n", ntohs(servaddr.sin6_port));

     }
len = sizeof(servaddr);
  if(getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &len) < -1)
   {
     perror("getsockname error.\n");
     exit(1);
   }
  if(listen(sockfd, 5) < 0)
   {
     perror("Error on listen.\n");
     exit(1);
   }

  return sockfd;
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int newsockfd;
  fd_set rdfs;
  int tsock, usock;
  int fd, ndfs;
  struct sockaddr_in6 client_tcp;
  int childpid;
  tsock = create_tcp();
  bzero(&client_tcp, sizeof(client_tcp));
  socklen_t clientlen_tcp;
  bzero(&sendData, sizeof(sendData));
  bzero(&recvData, sizeof(recvData));
  clientlen_tcp = sizeof(client_tcp);
  signal(SIGCHLD, reaper);
  ndfs = tsock+1;                                   
  FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
    pthread_t thread_id;
signal(SIGCHLD, reaper);
  while(1)
      {
      FD_SET(tsock, &rdfs);
      if(select(ndfs, &rdfs, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, (struct timeval *)0) < 0)
       {
     perror("Select on error.\n");
     exit(1);
       }
      if(FD_ISSET(tsock, &rdfs))
       {
     newsockfd = accept(tsock, (struct sockaddr *) &client_tcp, &clientlen_tcp);
     if(newsockfd < 0)
         {
      perror("Error on accept.\n");
      exit(1);
     }


pthread_mutex_init (&lock, NULL);

        if( pthread_create( &thread_id , NULL , tcp_work , (void *) &newsockfd) < 0)
        {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
        }
    puts("TCP client connected");

    if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
        }

pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

        
       
        }

        FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
  }
}




void *tcp_work(void *socket_desc)
{

    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;

  int count = 1; int bytes_read = 0;
int Mx = 255;
char data[Mx];
char buf1[] = "1";


char num[50];
char exit[] = "exit";

  struct s_Data recvData;
  bzero(&recvData, sizeof(recvData));


    while(1)
    { 

        bytes_read = recv(sock, &num, sizeof(num), 0);
        printf("%s", num);
        if(bytes_read > 0)
         { 
        
pthread_mutex_lock (&lock);
num[50] = '\0';
    point[atoi(num)-1] = 'X';
    if (check()>0)
    {
        
        send(sock,&exit,sizeof(exit),0);
    }
    else{
        
        srand(time(0));
        int i;
        i = 1+rand()%9;
        do {
            i = 1+rand()%9;
        }while(point[i-1]=='X'||point[i-1]=='O');
        point[i-1] = 'O';
     send(sock,my_itoa(i,num),sizeof(num),0);

}


        
pthread_mutex_unlock (&lock);

     }
        
        else break;
    }
    
return 0;
}




        
pthread_mutex_unlock (&lock);

     }
        
        else break;
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

Клиент:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

//static const uint8_t myaddr[16] = { 0x20, 0x01, 0x08, 0x88, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 };
char num[50];
char message[] = "Hello";

char point [9]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
int check (); 
void show(); 


int check () 
{
    if (((*point=='X')&&(*(point+1)=='X')&&(*(point+2)=='X'))||((*(point+3)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+5)=='X'))||((*(point+6)=='X')&&(*(point+7)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*point=='X')&&(*(point+3)=='X')&&(*(point+6)=='X'))||((*(point+1)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+7)=='X'))||((*(point+2)=='X')&&(*(point+5)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*point=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+8)=='X'))||((*(point+2)=='X')&&(*(point+4)=='X')&&(*(point+6)=='X')))
    {printf(" \nX wins!");  return 1;}
    else if (((*point=='O')&&(*(point+1)=='O')&&(*(point+2)=='O'))||((*(point+3)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+5)=='O'))||((*(point+6)=='O')&&(*(point+7)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*point=='O')&&(*(point+3)=='O')&&(*(point+6)=='O'))||((*(point+1)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+7)=='O'))||((*(point+2)=='O')&&(*(point+5)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*point=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+8)=='O'))||((*(point+2)=='O')&&(*(point+4)=='O')&&(*(point+6)=='O')))
    {printf("\nO wins!");  return 1;}
    if (((*point=='X')||(*point=='O'))&&((*(point+1)=='X')||(*(point+1)=='O'))&&((*(point+2)=='X')||(*(point+2)=='O'))&&((*(point+3)=='X')||(*(point+3)=='O'))&&((*(point+4)=='X')||(*(point+4)=='O'))&&((*(point+5)=='X')||(*(point+5)=='O'))&&((*(point+6)=='X')||(*(point+6)=='O'))&&((*(point+7)=='X')||(*(point+7)=='O'))&&((*(point+8)=='X')||(*(point+8)=='O')))
    {printf("\ndraw!"); return 1;}
    return 0;
}

void show() 
{
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        printf("%c ",*(point+i));
        j++;
        if (j==3) {j=0; printf("\n");}
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
    void sigalarm(int);
    if(argc!=2) {
        printf("Вы забыли указать адрес и порт.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    addr.sin6_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
  //  addr.sin6_addr = "::1/128";//inet_addr(argv[1]);
   inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1/128", &addr.sin6_addr);
   // memcpy(addr.sin6_addr.s6_addr, myaddr, sizeof myaddr);
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(2);
    }
    show();
        while(1)
    {
        scanf ("%s", num);
        
        point[atoi(num)-1] = 'X';
        //show();
        check();
        
        send(sock, num, sizeof(num), 0);
        recv(sock, num, sizeof(num), 0);
        if(num[0] == 'e')
        {
            check();
            break;
        }
        else{point[atoi(num)-1] = 'O';
         show();
         check();
        }
      
      }
        
        

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: проверьте возвращаемое значение у `inet_pton` в клиенте. И если оно равно -1 то попробуйте поменять адрес "::1/128" без маски  => "::1"

Comment: Alex, огромное Вам спасибо! Я сделала как Вы сказали и теперь работает!